# Classes cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java

I have two packages. The class I want to import from the first package is declared as PUBLIC. Despite, when I test a file from the second package it shows me compilation errors like this:

> PUBLICclass is not public in mypackage; cannot be accessed from outside package

I tried to add a public constructor to the class from the first package, but it doesn't make any difference.

Do you have any ideas? I use Netbeans 7.

The class from the first package looks like below:

```
public class PUBLICclass extends AbstractClass { public PUBLICclass() { } }
```

Comment: Can you add the class declaration (class XYZ together with the constructors) to the question?

Comment: Also, make sure there's a space between the keyword "public" (no need to capitalize it) and the class name.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, forget to `import` this `PUBLICclass` in the Java file which *uses* it? (Outside of the package where `PUBLICclass` is located.)

Comment: @user268396 I have it, and the error is about that line just.

Comment: What I meant is that it looks like you imported the class using something like “`import PUBLICclass;`”, when you need something more like `import mypackage.name.PUBLICclass;`.

Comment: Awful naming convention.  I hope it's just an example, not the real class names in your app.

Comment: @duffymo that's just an example ;-)

Comment: I got this error when trying to build with Ant. It turned out that two versions of the same class were being loaded by `javac`, and the first class was not public.

I had to enable `verbose="on"` on the `<javac>` task so I could find out where this non-public class was, then modified the task to `<exclude>` the problematic JAR.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Let me guess

Your initial declaration of class `PUBLICClass` was not public, then you made it `Public`, can you try to clean and rebuild your project ?

Comment: LOL I've just cleaned and rebuilt the project and there is no problem now.

Comment: In my case, restarting the IDE (I'm using Android Studio) helped.

Comment: I just deleted that class and created a new one with just different name

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol As far as I am aware, restarting Android Studio causes a clean and build to occur.

Comment: For some reason clean and build doesn't work, but manually deleting the output and build folders did the trick.

Answer (score 23):

```
public SmartSaverCals(Context context)
{
    this.context= context;
}
```

add public to Your constructor.in my case problem solved

Answer (score 7):

Check the default superclass's constructor. It need be public or protected.

Comment: Thanks, that's what was causing the issue in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have two `PUBLICclass` classes in your project, where one is public (the one of which you posted the signature here), and another one which is package visible, and you import the wrong one in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try removing "new" keyword and see if works.
Because last time I got this error when I tried creating `Typeface` something like this:

```
Typeface typeface = new Typeface().create("Arial",Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

`closeDrawers(boolean)` is not public in `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. **Cannot** be accessed from outside package

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the default when you make a class is not public as far as packages are considered.  Make sure that you actually write `public class [MyClass] {` when defining your class.  I've made this mistake more times than I care to admit.