# Using defaultNaming for dynamic windowed writes in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am following along with answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519834/how-to-write-to-a-file-name-defined-at-runtime/48531741#48531741) and [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) in order to perform a dynamic windowed write on my data at the end of a pipeline. Here is what I have so far:

```
static void applyWindowedWrite(PCollection<String> stream) {
    stream.apply(
        FileIO.<String, String>writeDynamic()
            .by(Event::getKey)
            .via(TextIO.sink())
            .to("gs://some_bucket/events/")
            .withNaming(key -> defaultNaming(key, ".json")));
}
```

But NetBeans warns me about a syntax error on the last line:

`FileNaming is not public in Write; cannot be accessed outside package`

How do I make `defaultNaming` available to my pipeline so that I can use it for dynamic writes. Or, if that isn't possible, what should I be doing instead?

Comment: This does not look like a beam/dataflow issue but rather like a java one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487678/9251751) answer in an older question offers an explanation on why java throws this type of error and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386798/9251751) a possible solution. Does any of them help?

Comment: I agree it is a Java path issue. However, I'm looking for some help in the Beam context in using that `defaultNaming` method. The post I refer to shows the use of this method similar to how I am using it, and yet apparently it does not throw the same error. I am wondering why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting what I figured out in case someone else comes across this.

There were three issues with how I was attempting to use `writeDynamic()` before.

1. Previously I had been using Beam version 2.3.0, which does indeed describe `FileNaming` as a class internal to `FileIO.Write`. Beam 2.4.0 defines `FileNaming` as a `public static interface` making it available externally.
2. Fully resolving/importing `defaultNaming`. Rather than calling `defaultNaming` directly - as it is called in the example documentation - it must be invoked as `FileIO.Write.defaultNaming` since `FileIO` is the package I actually imported.
3. Adding `withDestinationCoder` was also required to perform the dynamic write.

The final solution ended up looking like this.

```
static void applyWindowedWrite(PCollection<String> stream) {
    stream.apply(FileIO.<String, String>writeDynamic()
                .by(Event::getKey)
                .via(TextIO.sink())
                .to("gs://some_bucket/events/")
                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withNaming(key -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(key, ".json")));
}
```

Where `Event::getKey` is a static function defined within the same package with the signature `public static String getKey(String event)`.

This performs a windowed write which will write one file per window (as defined by the `.withNumShards(1)` method). This assumes the window has been defined in a previous step. A `GroupByKey` is not required prior to writing since it is done in the process of writing whenever the number of shards is defined explicitly. See the [FileIO documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) for more details under "Writing files -> How many shards are generated per pane".