# How to use FileIO.writeDynamic() in Apache Beam 2.6 to write to multiple output paths?

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am using Apache Beam 2.6 to read from a single Kafka topic and write the output to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Now I want to alter the pipeline so that it is reading multiple topics and writing them out as `gs://bucket/topic/...`

When reading only a single topic I used `TextIO` in the last step of my pipeline:

```
TextIO.write()
    .to(
        new DateNamedFiles(
            String.format("gs://bucket/data%s/", suffix), currentMillisString))
    .withWindowedWrites()
    .withTempDirectory(
        FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(
            String.format("gs://bucket/tmp%s/%s/", suffix, currentMillisString)))
    .withNumShards(1));
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241407/5497956) is a similar question, which code I tried to adapt.

```
FileIO.<EventType, Event>writeDynamic()
    .by(
        new SerializableFunction<Event, EventType>() {
          @Override
          public EventType apply(Event input) {
            return EventType.TRANSFER; // should return real type here, just a dummy
          }
        })
    .via(
        Contextful.fn(
            new SerializableFunction<Event, String>() {
              @Override
              public String apply(Event input) {
                return "Dummy"; // should return the Event converted to a String
              }
            }),
        TextIO.sink())
    .to(DynamicFileDestinations.constant(new DateNamedFiles("gs://bucket/tmp%s/%s/",
                                                            currentMillisString),
        new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
          @Override
          public String apply(String input) {
            return null; // Not sure what this should exactly, but it needs to 
                         // include the EventType into the path
          }
        }))
    .withTempDirectory(
        FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(
            String.format("gs://bucket/tmp%s/%s/", suffix, currentMillisString)))
    .withNumShards(1))
```

The [official JavaDoc](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.6.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L169) contains example code which seem to have outdated method signatures. (The `.via` method seems to have switched the order of the arguments). I' furthermore stumbled across the example in `FileIO` which confused me - shouldn't `TransactionType` and `Transaction` [in this line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.6.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L296) change places?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a night of sleep and a fresh start I figured out the solution, I used the functional Java 8 style as it makes the code shorter (and more readable):

```
  .apply(
    FileIO.<String, Event>writeDynamic()
        .by((SerializableFunction<Event, String>) input -> input.getTopic())
        .via(
            Contextful.fn(
                (SerializableFunction<Event, String>) input -> input.getPayload()),
            TextIO.sink())
        .to(String.format("gs://bucket/data%s/", suffix)
        .withNaming(type -> FileNaming.getNaming(type, "", currentMillisString))
        .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
        .withTempDirectory(
            String.format("gs://bucket/tmp%s/%s/", suffix, currentMillisString))
        .withNumShards(1));
```

Explanation:

- `Event` is a Java POJO containing the payload of the Kafka message and the topic it belongs to, it is parsed in a `ParDo` after the `KafkaIO` step
- `suffix` is a either `dev` or empty and set by environment variables
- `currentMillisString`contains the timestamp when the whole pipeline
  was launched so that new files don't overwrite old files on GCS when
  a pipeline gets restarted
- `FileNaming` implements a custom naming and receives the type of the event (the topic) in it's constructor, it uses a custom formatter to write to daily partitioned "sub-folders" on GCS:

  ```
  class FileNaming implements FileIO.Write.FileNaming {
    static FileNaming getNaming(String topic, String suffix, String currentMillisString) {
      return new FileNaming(topic, suffix, currentMillisString);
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich")));

    private final String topic;
    private final String suffix;
    private final String currentMillisString;

    private String filenamePrefixForWindow(IntervalWindow window) {
      return String.format(
          "%s/%s/%s_", topic, FORMATTER.print(window.start()), currentMillisString);
    }

    private FileNaming(String topic, String suffix, String currentMillisString) {
      this.topic = topic;
      this.suffix = suffix;
      this.currentMillisString = currentMillisString;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFilename(
        BoundedWindow window,
        PaneInfo pane,
        int numShards,
        int shardIndex,
        Compression compression) {

      IntervalWindow intervalWindow = (IntervalWindow) window;
      String filenamePrefix = filenamePrefixForWindow(intervalWindow);
      String filename =
          String.format(
              "pane-%d-%s-%05d-of-%05d%s",
              pane.getIndex(),
              pane.getTiming().toString().toLowerCase(),
              shardIndex,
              numShards,
              suffix);
      String fullName = filenamePrefix + filename;
      return fullName;
    }
  }
  ```