# Write multiple files on GS in dataflow based on key based grouping in the pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a KV collection created by grouping and the goal is to write each V to a different file(V is a list of Strings).
Referring to this code,
[How to use FileIO.writeDynamic() in Apache Beam 2.6 to write to multiple output paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879336/how-to-use-fileio-writedynamic-in-apache-beam-2-6-to-write-to-multiple-output/53558005#53558005) ,
I follow that FileIO.dynamic write will solve the purpose.
However does it consider hot key fanouts in grouping?
What is the best way to write to multiple files based on keys?
Also name of the file has to be key with values written in it.